# Matching same unknown characters in two columns

Tags: mysql, select, like

So here is the situation. I have a database with values in columns that look something like this

```
field_0_data1, field_0_data2, field_1_data1, field_1_data2
```

Is it possible to only select the columns where the values in the middle is the same. Honestly I'm not even sure if I'm asking right but.

Say it was something like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column1 LIKE "field\_(%)\_data1" AND column2 = "fields\_\1\_data2"
```

where \1 is a back reference to (%)

I'm sure I have the terminology wrong but hopefully you can understand what I'm trying to do.

"No, this cannot be done." is a valid answer.

Thanks

**Edit: More information**

Let's say that the table looks something like this.

```
ID | page_id | key           | value 
1  | 100     | field_0_data1 | 1
2  | 100     | field_0_data2 | 500
3  | 100     | field_1_data1 | 2
4  | 100     | field_1_data2 | 1000
```

So what I need to do is in one query I want to search for a value in field_%_data1 and get the value from the matching field_%_data2. So what I need to do is match the result of the % when getting the value of the second field.

**Edit: Even more information**
I know I asked this a long time ago and there probably isn't an answer. While I no longer need this at the moment, it would still be nice to find a solution because I'm sure I'll run into it again in the future.

The query I'm looking for is to query a WordPress database. I did not say WP because I already know that this is impossible using something that WP provides and I would need to build my own SQL query to do it. This also has to do with Advance Custom Fields (ACF) but also not something that it can do.

I have 1 piece of information, a value that might be in a repeater field. Let's say that the value I have is "1000". I have no other information to work with. In a single query I need to be able to have it return the value "2". Either of the fields with the key "field_0_data2" and/or "field_1_data2" could hold the value that I'm looking for.

Yes, this could be done with multiple queries and some PHP in between. (please exuse the code, it is not meant to be perfect and I know there are errors in it, it's just to highlight the example)

1)

```
SELECT ID, key FROM table WHERE key LIKE "field\_%\_data2" AND value ="1000"
```

2)

```
$row = preg_match('/field_([0-9]+)_data2/', $key, $matches);
$new_key = 'field_'.$matches[1].'_data1';
```

3)

```
SELECT value FROM table WHERE id = "{$ID}" AND key = "{$new_key}"
```

What I was hoping what some type of back-referencing in the SQL language that would accomplish the same thing is a single query.

Once again, telling me that this is impossible is completely acceptable. It will keep me from wasting time in the future looking for something that does not exist.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Is your example WHERE condition correct? for `column2` the first part is "field**s**" instead of "field" and the second part of `column2` is looking for "data**2**"? Can you please give a few examples of possible matches since it seems like there might be a few variations?

Comment: Sorry for being incomplete, it is MySQL.

Comment: Sorry, again, trying to figure out how to add what you need

Comment: Can you reexplain your question, it seems like there's something missing in what you've explained about what you need?

Comment: Restructure your schema to facilitate that `SELECT`.  Don't try to make SQL do something it cannot do.

Comment: I need to search this table, find a value in tha column, match the key column to it matching field_XX_ key and then check to see if the value in the matching key also matches the criteria that I'm looking for. What I really need to return is the page_id values that match this convoluted search and because of other limitations I need to do it in a single query. Like I originally said, not is a valid answer. Restructuring is not really an option. I'm going to assume that since no one understands what I'm talking about that this is probably not possible. Like I said, no by be the only answer.

Comment: Are all the data in the column of the same format `field_X_dataY` where X is number and Y is either 0 or 1?